# WP8 emulator "jumpy" on sounds

Tags: windows-phone-8, playback, mediaelement, audio, windows-phone-8-emulator

### Background

I have a simple app that is supposed to play 2 sounds, one after another.

### The problem

On the windows phone8 emulator, I keep getting the first sound being cut in the middle, and sometimes I have the second sound play twice.

### What I've tried

I use in XAML the event:

```
MediaEnded="mediaElement_MediaEnded"
```

which there i set a new source to the MediaElement object:

```
mediaElement.Source = new Uri(_soundFileToOpen, UriKind.Relative);
mediaElement.Play();
```

I've also tried to register to the event :

```
MediaOpened="mediaElement_MediaOpened"
```

and only there to start the audio (with AutoPlay="False" of course), but it didn't help.

### Question

Why is this happening, and can I fix it?

Maybe it's a bug with the emulator, and on a real device it will work fine?

Comment: Please show a complete example of what you're doing that recreates the issue. Have you tried on an actual device to see if it's emulator dependent?

Comment: I've shown the relavant code. the xaml simply has the mediaElement and in the code i have an event that will set the Source to a specific file . there is nothing special in the code. About a device, sadly I don't have one so that's why I ask about the emulator, if anyone else has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Even when forcing Position to 0.
It plays part of file, then starts all over again with correct sound.
From time to time played sound is as it should be.

There is something wrong with emulator for sure...